# ListView problem while clicking

Tags: android, listview

This is my ListView xml file and i have different xml for row(every item of listview),Nothing to do with that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:listSelector="#ffffff"  
        android:clickable="false"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"
        style="@style/ProgressStyle"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

     />

</LinearLayout>
```

When i am clicking this listview it is becoming white as because it is set **android:listSelector="#ffffff"**. But when i m removing this from xml file then when i am clicking then the item on which i click it is showing some color(in my case yellow in emulator and red in device).It should not show because **android:clickable="false** is set. Anyone having any idea?

Comment: set cacheColorHint on your list to transparent (#00000000).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is byDefault set, if you dont want any color then you can set a **transparent** color in xml

```
android:listSelector="#00000000"
```

Comment: Sorry i went for some work.So i forgot to accept.Now i accepted.   :)